# Get error while trying to parse into a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization

I want to build a payment API but I always get the following error:

> {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0."}

The code looks like this:

```cs
var priceAmount = txtBoxTopUpBalance.Text;
            

var client = new RestClient("https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/invoice");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request1.AddHeader("x-api-key", apiKey);
request1.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var body = @"{" + "\n" +
    @"  ""price_amount"":" + priceAmount + "\n" +
    @"  ""price_currency"": ""usd""," + "\n" +
    @"  ""order_id"": ""RGDBP-21314""," + "\n" +
    @"  ""order_description"": ""order #1""," + "\n" +
    @"  ""ipn_callback_url"": ""https://nowpayments.io""," + "\n" +
    @"  ""success_url"": ""https://nowpayments.io""," + "\n" +
    @"  ""cancel_url"": ""https://nowpayments.io""" + "\n" +
    @"}" + "\n" +
    @"" + "\n" +
    @"";
request1.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response1 = client.Execute(request1);

JObject responseObject = JObject.Parse(response1.Content); // <--The error occurs here
invoiceUrl = responseObject["invoice_url"].ToString();
```

The issue is that 'body' can't be parsed into a JSON object.

When I remove the priceAmount var it works, but it's necessary.

I'm still a beginner, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Didn't you post basically the same question a day or so ago? Please don't post duplicate questions, but instead edit the *existing* question in response to comments requesting more information.

Answer (score 2):

Don't build (serialize) the JSON manually. There will be a high chance of getting exposed to syntax errors such as missing quotes, missing opening/closing braces, etc.

Use JSON libraries such as *System.Text.Json* or *Newtonsoft.Json* to serialize to JSON.

From the sample [NOWPayments API Create Invoice documentation](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7907941/S1a32n38#3e3ce25e-f43f-4636-bbd9-11560e46048b), you should pass the `price_amount` as the number type.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

var body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
{
    price_amount = decimal.Parse(priceAmount),
    price_currency = "usd",
    order_id = "RGDBP-21314",
    order_description = "order #1",
    ipn_callback_url = "https://nowpayments.io",
    success_url = "https://nowpayments.io",
    cancel_url = "https://nowpayments.io"
});
```

Or

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    price_amount = decimal.Parse(priceAmount),
    price_currency = "usd",
    order_id = "RGDBP-21314",
    order_description = "order #1",
    ipn_callback_url = "https://nowpayments.io",
    success_url = "https://nowpayments.io",
    cancel_url = "https://nowpayments.io"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, need "," after priceAmount, but IMHO better to use this syntax. It was just tested and working Ok.

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.nowpayments.io/");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("v1/invoice",Method.Post);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    var body = new
    {
        price_amount = decimal.Parse(priceAmount),
        price_currency = "usd",
        order_id = "RGDBP-21314",
        order_description = "order #1",
        ipn_callback_url = "https://nowpayments.io",
        success_url = "https://nowpayments.io",
        cancel_url = "https://nowpayments.io"
    };
    request.AddJsonBody(body);

var response = client.Execute(request);
    JObject responseObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
    
    if (response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        var invoiceUrl = responseObject["invoice_url"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        var errorMessage = responseObject["message"].ToString();
    }
```